# Como adaptar layout de acordo com o redimensionamento do browser?

Tags: javascript, html, css, loop

Construí uma função para ler o tamanho da janela pela qual o usuário está acessando o site, comparar com um break-point padrão que escolhi e após isso adaptar o layout. Eu coloquei um exemplo de alteração em um elemento ícone que é alterado quando identificado o break-point.

```
function adaptarBtn () {

            let pontoDeParada1 = 768;
            let pontoDeParada2 = 900;
            let larguraTela = window.innerWidth;       
            let btnNavegar = document.getElementById("fas");

            if(larguraTela >= pontoDeParada1 && larguraTela < pontoDeParada2){
                btnNavegar.className = 'fas fa-bars fa-lg';
            }else if(larguraTela < pontoDeParada1){
                btnNavegar.className = "fas fa-bars";
                console.log(btnNavegar);
            }
        }
```

Funcionou, o único problema é que o layout só se adapta após eu fazer o refresh do documento, e a minha intenção era fazer isso acontecer também ao fazer o redimensionamento da janela pelo browser.

---

Como fazer?

Comment: Coloca essa função para ser executada no evento onresize do javascript, dá uma olhada em https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onresize.asp.

Comment: Com CSS e @media queries fazes isso, não?

Answer (score 0):

Você não deveria estar usando javascript pra isso, essa sua alteração tem impacto somente no visual do seu site e isso deve ser responsabilidade do CSS.

Você pode usar um @media query para fazer isso. Com essa query você define como uma classe se comporta em determinado tamanho de tela. Nesse exemplo que você deu seria algo como:

```
   @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 900px) {
      .fa-bars {
       //Comportamento da classe em dispositivos com tela entre 768px e 900px
      }
    }

    @media (max-width: 768px) {
      .fa-bars {
        //Comportamento da classe em dispositivos com tela menores que 768px
      }
    }
```

Comment: Eis aí o grande problema, os medias-query só funcionam ao dar reload na página, quero atrelar a mudança de layout juntamente ao redimensionamento manual feito com o mouse.